# Retrieving Specific firebase data from a symfony 3 application

Tags: php, json, symfony, get, nosql

i'm here trying to use symfony 3.1.* and firebase for a project.
I've been reading the documentation about retrieving data and i am able to do so but the only problem i am getting is that i am not able to find how to retrieve a specific data from firebase db through the symfony app using php. 
Here is the data im storing in json format:

[Data in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaKmH.jpg)
here is a piece of php code im using to retrieve all the tree structure.[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN0Za.jpg)]

```
public function getUserFirebase(Request $request)
{
    $path = $this->getParameter('default_path');
    $firebase = $this->get('app.firebase_connect_controller')->getFireBaseConnection();


    $value = $firebase->get($path);
    $data = json_decode($value, true);
    return new JsonResponse($data);
}
```